# Value replacement function with ambiguity protection

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm trying to replace values in string and I want to prevent potential confusions.

My function:

```
<?php
function newValue($str, $from, $to) {
    return str_ireplace($from, $to, $str);
}

$new = '{NAME}';
$var = newValue('This is {TYPE} and this {NAME} value should be replaced', '{TYPE}', $new);
$var = newValue('This is {TYPE} and this {NAME} value should be replaced', '{NAME}', 'string');

echo $var;
// This is string and this string value should be replaced
```

Is there a better way to do replacement so can avoid situation when 'replacement' have the same value as 'search' is named. Its probably not going to happen but I want to know the best way. I'm looking for the most simple function - no ifs and sprintf etc.

Comment: Your code seems to work correctly. Once you say you want to prevent confusions, later to avoid situation when 'replacement' equals 'search'. Could you elaborate a bit more on what is the problem with your code? It does exactly what `str_ireplace()` is for.

Comment: Maybe you can escape `{` and `}` in `$to` to prevent collisions?

Comment: @dfsq, can you demonstrate what you mean ?

Comment: @Michal, I know it works. I just want to find unequivocal way.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works...
$vars = newValue('This is {TYPE} and this {NAME} value should be replaced. First change is {TYPE}, Second change is {NAME}', array('{TYPE}' , '{NAME}'), array('string1' , 'string2'));

echo $vars;